# Como retornar a sequência da semana no período informado?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia, preciso retornar a sequência da semana do mês (do período informado) em dois campos, data inicial e final. Em `PHP` e `MySQL`.
Atualmente retorna o Número da semana no ano, segue print para melhor entendimento.

Código SQL:

```
SELECT YEAR(dadf331.datlan)      AS ano, 
       MONTHNAME(dadf331.datlan) AS mes, 
       WEEK(dadf331.datlan)      AS semana, 
       SUM(totped)               AS totalv 
  FROM dadf331 
 WHERE tipped = 0 
   AND datlan >= '2017-09-01' 
   AND datlan <= '2017-09-30' 
 GROUP BY semana 
 ORDER BY semana ASC
```

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: editado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o campo `sequencia_semana` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT YEAR(dadf331.datlan)                                                                                AS ano,
       MONTHNAME(dadf331.datlan)                                                                           AS mes,
       WEEK(dadf331.datlan)                                                                                AS semana,
       SUM(totped)                                                                                         AS totalv,
       (WEEK(dadf331.datlan) + 1) - WEEK(DATE_ADD(dadf331.datlan, INTERVAL - DAY(dadf331.datlan) + 1 DAY)) AS sequencia_semana
  FROM dadf331
 WHERE tipped = 0
   AND datlan >= '2017-09-01'
   AND datlan <= '2017-09-30'
 GROUP BY semana
 ORDER BY semana ASC
```

Dessa forma você calcula a semana do primeiro dia o mês e subtrai a semana da data desse valor calculado, tendo assim a semana dentro do mês.

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fc965/1)

Comment: Beleza, era isso mesmo!